# How to identify my cloned C drive in Dell boot options?

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, bootable-media, dell-precision

I have a `Dell Precision Tower 3620` running Windows 10 and I installed a new 512Gb internal SSD (size exactly matches my C-drive). The new drive mapped to H because I have some other external drives already mapped. I cloned C to H using Macrium Reflect and it worked fine. Now I'm trying to boot to H as a test, to see if it will work in case my C doesn't boot up someday. See my boot options:

[image]

In the `File System List` I'm guessing it shows my C and H drives but I don't really know. Maybe it doesn't show C at all, but 2 other bootable options? I think the new H drive is actually a lower index number than existing C so I don't want to make assumptions about sequence.

**Question: How can I tell which of those cryptic items in File System List matches my new SSD H drive?**

Note: This PC is aggressively managed by my company and has Sophos running like a watchdog on there, and everything is encrypted by BitLocker (except for my new H drive that I just installed). So I hesitate to turn off Secure Boot. I fear if I disable that, it won't be able to boot up at all. But I'm not sure. The new H drive is a pure clone of C, including bootloader info. I tried this whole "clone C and boot to the clone" thing on my home PC (also Win10), it works great, and I can boot to the clone. I have the bitlocker recovery key, so I'm not worried about that.

Another question is, will I have to Bitlock my new H drive to make it bootable? Will that even work? I think the cloned drive is already encrypted because it's a clone of encrypted C, but it's not yet *managed* by bitlocker. I believe there is a difference. Will my bitlocker unlock key work on the new H drive, if required?

I have tried using `gdisk64.exe` to tell me which guids map to which bootable drives, but it does nothing more than display this error: `Problem opening xx for reading.`

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

**EDIT #1**

At `harrymc`'s suggestion I ran `diskpart` against both my `C` and my `H` (C-CLONE) and here are the results, which I'm still not seeing how to connect with bios `File System List`:

```
C:
THNSN5512GPU7 NVMe TOSHIBA 512GB
Disk ID: {7B965662-7DFC-4920-97E8-17C82A709FAE}
Type   : RAID
Status : Online
Path   : 3
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1700)#RAID(P03T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 5     C   OS           NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 6         ESP          FAT32  Partition    500 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 7                      NTFS   Partition    526 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 8         Image        NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy    Hidden


H: (Cloned disk)
SPCC Solid State Disk
Disk ID: {C52A1A60-B0F2-494C-B8E0-7448685BA574}
Type   : RAID
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 1
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1700)#RAID(P00T01L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 1     H   C-BAK        NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2         ESP          FAT32  Partition    500 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3                      NTFS   Partition    526 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4         Image        NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy    Hidden
```

**EDIT #2**

Here is the powershell command and its results, as suggested by harrymc:

```
PS C: Get-Partition | Select-Object -Property AccessPaths,DiskNumber,DriveLetter,PartitionNumber

AccessPaths                                              DiskNumber DriveLetter PartitionNumber
-----------                                              ---------- ----------- ---------------
                                                                  0                          1
{D:\, \\?\Volume{c7a52f34-58f9-40df-a7d8-2241f85cf31b}\}          0           D              2
{\\?\Volume{4735c283-d00e-49ec-b561-a41342bf5650}\}               2                          1
                                                                  2                          2
{C:\, \\?\Volume{f37cfc19-72e6-4491-8105-2f6038f0e49e}\}          2           C              3
{\\?\Volume{096c2a6c-684e-4294-82b8-cfc05e5194ab}\}               2                          4
{\\?\Volume{9a0ceaf9-80bd-44a6-b98b-fad5b7d45e26}\}               2                          5
{E:\, \\?\Volume{0b58388b-0145-4f3b-a205-4902a8060b64}\}          4           E              1
{F:\, \\?\Volume{66854805-0000-0000-0080-000000000000}\}          3           F              1
{\\?\Volume{770a91d0-88af-4639-b275-43f7c115890e}\}               1                          1
                                                                  1                          2
{H:\, \\?\Volume{bc911a9e-0590-48df-98d1-779044743f14}\}          1           H              3
{\\?\Volume{81891912-e45a-4a4a-a28a-d76aeee5bd21}\}               1                          4
{\\?\Volume{10f118f3-7dc3-4b0a-98a2-53e5c1cb2b4b}\}               1                          5
```

One one hand it's great that I can now see guids from the bios screenshot matching actual drives as per powershell. The problem is that guid #1 in bios matches my F drive which is a non-bootable data drive. And guid #2 in bios matches my D drive which is a non-bootable data drive. Am I misinterpreting the File System List in bios? Ultimately I just need to know how to identify my H drive (C-CLONE) in bios so I can boot to that instead of C.

Comment: Are these SSDs SATA drives by chance?  If you are experienced, and you are not an Administrator, you really SHOULD NOT be modifying the configuration of the device in question.  If you change the configuration of the system, and you have BitLocker enabled on your system, you will be required (without any way to bypass) to input the recovery key for the drive.  You should ask for the assistance of your network administrators to accomplish this task.  I am actually shocked, installing the new SSD, didn't result in you being asked for the recovery key since it's a clone of the system drive.

Comment: Ramhound, why do you assume I don't have the recovery key? Also, why do you assume I would even be asked for the key prior to booting to the cloned drive? I haven't yet booted to the cloned drive because I don't know which it is yet, as per my screenshot...and thus my post here.

Comment: One strong-arm method: Take out the C disk, connect the clone in its place, then boot. If it works, then everything is OK and you know you can recover from the failure of C.

Comment: Low-tech solution: Take physically out the old disk and then you will know for sure.

Comment: harrymc: I agree but that's a huge pain given my setup. Is there not a digital way?

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUID that is shown is the unique access-path ID of the partition.

This PowerShell command will show all partitions GUIDs with their
disk numbers. The disk numbers are the same as shown in Disk Management:

```
Get-Partition | Select-Object -Property AccessPaths,DiskNumber,DriveLetter,PartitionNumber
```

Note that `AccessPaths` is actually an array and a partition may have more
than one, as for example is the case for the partition with the drive-letter
of `C`.

**Example:**

This your BIOS boot menu:

[image]

There are two GUIDs here:

1. 770a91d0-88af-4639-b275-43f7c115890e
2. 4735c283-d00e-49ec-b561-a41342bf5650

In your output of the above PowerShell command I marked the important parts:

[image]

So we now know the disks to which these two GUIDs relate:

1. 770a91d0-88af-4639-b275-43f7c115890e - Same disk as H
2. 4735c283-d00e-49ec-b561-a41342bf5650 - Same disk as C

---

**Old answer** (kept for the clarity of the comments below)

This should help to identify the disk:

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Run `diskpart`
- Select the first disk with the command `select disk 0`
- Enter the command `detail disk`
- The value for `Location Path` will be similar to the one
  shown under "File System List:"
- You may compare this with the second disk by doing the same with `select disk 1`.

Comment: AFAIK the GUIDs shown there are partition GUIDs of the ESPs instead of the disk GUIDs

Comment: @TomYan: He's not looking for the GUID but for the BIOS hardware location path.

Comment: Ah you are talking about the first half of the path

Comment: harrymc: This seems very promising. I located both my C (disk 2) and my cloned C (disk 1) by label - but neither of the Disk IDs (guids) matched either of the guids in the File System List.

Comment: Look at the value of "Location Path" which starts with "PCIROOT". The device path should be derivable from it. If your values are different, add to your post a screenshot of the command "detail disk" for both disks.

Comment: harrymc, I posted the values from `diskpart` as an edit in my original post. What do you think?

Comment: I think I found it. See my new answer.

Comment: `aecc20b9-3028-4a29-acc2-9c9faa5f06a1` isn't your `C:`, but the EFI system partition of the disk that `C:` resides on.

Comment: @TomYan: Of course, but it helps find the disk.

Comment: harrymc, I just posted my results of the powershell in the original post. I'm confused because neither of my bootable drives appear in that list; just 2 of my data drives.

Comment: I can see them: The first in the list is H and the second is C. The GUID is there. I can give more details later.

Comment: I'm anxious to learn your details; the guids in bios match only data drives, not H or C. ?

Comment: harrymc, I am grateful to you, thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder make sure you check that when boot with `770a91d0-88af-4639-b275-43f7c115890e`, it actually loads the system from `C-BAK` instead of `OS`. If it's the case, you should see the `Boot` flag being listed on the former instead, and the drive letter of it will most likely become `C:`.

Comment: Understood, Tom, thanks. Do you think I'll be required to enter the bitlocker password? And do you think I should have bitlocker maintain my C-BAK? I'm sure C-BAK is already encrypted, since it's a clone of C which is managed by bitlocker.

Answer (score 1):

You should have created a EFI System Partition and install (with `bcdboot`) or clone the boot files to it. If the BCD was cloned, you'll need to modify/update its osloader entry so that it boots H: instead of C:. (Note that H: will probably be assigned with C: after it's booted.)

If you did a full disk clone (i.e. partition table included), you might have to regenerate the partition GUIDs yourself (with e.g. gptfdisk) to avoid conflict/confusion to the boot manager and the UEFI.

After that you can use the disk entry (which is named with e.g. the vendor of the drive by the UEFI; it refers to the generic "portable" path: `\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`, which is in turn an identical copy of `\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` in Windows, which would cause the UEFI to "cache" an entry named "Windows Boot Manager", one per disk usually) to boot to the cloned Windows. Since Microsoft double-guarantees that any Windows installation can be booted without manual NVRAM registration, you hardly ever need to add an entry yourself.

Comment: Tom, I don't want to permanently boot to the new drive. Just once, so I can prove that it works. If I modify osloader entry, won't that make it permanent? I'd like to specify which SSD drive to boot to in the bios/setup. The new H drive is a pure clone of C, including bootloader info. I tried this whole thing on my home PC, it works great, and I can boot to the clone. I have the bitlocker recovery key, so I'm not worried about that. So...which of those 2 entries in my screenshot is for the clone? How can I discover that?

Comment: Are you trying to share the Windows Boot Manager / BCD? If you are then you shouldn't be adding boot entry to the UEFI but the BCD. If you are not, like I thought/suggested, what I asked you to modify is the BCD in a new/cloned set of boot files, which should be sitted on the "new" SSD as well, obviously. (And of course you'll need to create/clone them first, like I mentioned.)

Comment: If you want to keep a "perfect" clone, then I suggest that you just unplug the old drive from the box temporarily. If you have cloned the whole drive properly, the UEFI will be able to boot it "out-of-the-box" as well. (You might need to adjust the UEFI boot order, but not to adding entry.) If that's the case, you better never boot with both of them plugged. What I told you to do is to make them just "unique" enough to be plugged together for boot selection

Comment: If the UEFI somehow always requires you to add a boot entry for a newly found drive / ESP, then see which of those "cryptic" path goes away with the new drive unplugged. No point asking here.

Comment: A UEFI installation rarely ever use the main system partition as ESP as well (although not like always impossible), so `The new H drive is a pure clone of C, including bootloader info` is likely false unless you are using the letters to refer to the two SSDs.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Sorry if I'm not understanding, but is there not a way to discover, while logged into windows, which of my SATA SSDs (the C drive and my newly-installed H drive) maps to which of those GUIDs as listed under Boot Option -> File System List?

Comment: There certainly is. At least there's the Windows port/build of gdisk. Probably some built-in/native approach as well but I never bothered to find out.

Comment: Both GUIDs belong to the first partition (entry) of their respective disk btw.

Comment: Tom, thanks again, but I cannot get gdisk to tell me anything besides `Problem opening xx for reading.` I have googled all over the place for usage instructions and I keep ending up back here: https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html - none of those do anything, not sure if I'm doing this right. Can you give me a literal example? (I am using gdisk64.exe)

Comment: Use the administrator command prompt?

Comment: I did. Do you have an example of usage?

Comment: `gdisk64.exe 0:`? I haven't use it on Windows for quite some time and I'm not on PC at the moment so I can't really test.

Comment: Yeah, tried that initially, plus lots of other things based on docs - exact same error in all cases.

Comment: Does it help if you run just `gdisk64.exe` and then enter e.g. `0:` when it prompt for a device name?

Comment: Tom, I launched cmd as Admin, typed `gdisk64`, enter. Got prompt for `Type device filename`, entered `0`, enter...got `Problem opening 0 for reading`